# Deploying NodeJs App Correctly (git, modulus)

Tags: node.js, modulus.io

Modulus offers the option to deploy from the current directory or from a specified path.

My file structure is:

- package.json
- bower.json
- src (where the app is coded)
- dist (where gulp puts the ready app)
- dozens of other folder like e2e, seed, gulp, logs, mongobackub, node_modules, bower_components ...

Usually I just uploaded the dist folder with pushing the dist folder as a subtree. Now I want to improve my deployment process.

### Question 1)

Do I deploy from the main directory? It seems to take very long and actually only the dist folder + the package & bower files are needed for the application. But with looking forward to continuous integration e.g. codeship it looks like pushing all the folders may not be a bad idea, otherwise my unit tests maybe missing.

**EDIT:**

http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1702010-ignoring-files-during-a-deploy
To add a ignore file seems to be a solution to avoid changing the folder structure and focus only on the relevant files when deploying the whole application.

### Question 2)

Is there a way to just push the files which have changed. Uploading the whole directory takes up to 15 min and some Services like Amazon Payments require development on a server, because callbacks on localhost don't work. So a change can be very time intensive.